# The required resource is not available using Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a problem with using Spring. My problem is an 404 error and in the error message appear:

> The required resource is not available

How can I solve this?

My web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <display-name>Springapp</display-name>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>  
       <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
       <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.conexiona</groupId>
  <artifactId>springapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Beta8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.jbossts</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
        <version>4.16.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>springapp</finalName>
  </build>
  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  </properties>
</project>
```

My hello.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/include.jsp" %>

<html>
  <head><title><fmt:message key="title"/></title></head>
  <body>
    <h1><fmt:message key="heading"/></h1>
    <p><fmt:message key="greeting"/> <c:out value="${model.now}"/></p>
    <h3>Sensors</h3>
    <c:forEach items="${model.logs_19452055438107661658}" var="sens">
      <c:out value="${sens.idsensor}"/> <i>$<c:out value="${sens.temperature}"/>$<c:out value="${sens.timestamp}"/></i><br><br>
    </c:forEach>
  </body>
</html>
```

My include.jsp

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

My MongoSensorDao.java

```
package com.conexiona.springapp.repository;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import com.conexiona.springapp.domain.Sensor;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;

@Repository(value = "sensorDao")
public class MongoSensorDao implements SensorDao
{   
    EntityManager em;
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("172.16.1.25", 27017);
            
            DB db = mongo.getDB("kaa");
            DBCollection table = db.getCollection("logs_19452055438107661658");
            DBCursor document = table.find();
            
            try {
                while (document.hasNext())
                    System.out.println(document.next());
            } finally {
                document.close();
            }
            
        } catch (MongoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Sensor> getSensorList() {
        return em.createQuery("select p from Sensor p order by p.idsensor").getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void saveSensor(Sensor sens) {
        em.merge(sens);
    }

}
```

My app-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
 
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.conexiona.springapp.web" />

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>        
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

And my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
 
    <!-- holding properties for database connectivity /-->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration /-->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
      <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
      <property name="username"  value="${jdbc.username}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.conexiona.springapp.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.conexiona.springapp.service" />
    

</beans>
```

My controller

```
package com.conexiona.springapp.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.conexiona.springapp.service.SensorManager;

@Controller
public class SensorController {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private SensorManager sensorManager;

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello.htm")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String now = (new Date()).toString();
        logger.info("Returning hello view with " + now);

        Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        myModel.put("now", now);
        myModel.put("sensors", this.sensorManager.getSensors());

        return new ModelAndView("hello", "model", myModel);
    }


    public void setSensorManager(SensorManager sensorManager) {
        this.sensorManager = sensorManager;
    }
}
```

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB database but I only obtain 404 error.

Here is my project structure: [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAYrP.png)

Comment: Do you have any controller? Also, where is your `SensorDao` used?

Comment: Hello Roman. I have updated my question including my Controller. Thanks in advanced. SensorDao is a public Interface that I created.

Comment: What URL are use accessing when getting that 404 error? Is there any error message or exception trace in your servlet container logs?

Comment: you have keep three entries for <context:component-scan> in the spring configuration files. keeps it only one. i will suggest to keep only present in the app-config and change its value to com.conexiona.springapp. also make it value of logger level to TRACE and let us know the output to know the exact issue.

Comment: Try to hit the URL localhost:8080/springapp/hello.htm.
If u still get 404 then it might be spring doesn't know your controller component or may be doesn't know your tile view.

Comment: Hello Akshay. I have tried your solution and I obtain the same 404 error but now with some warnings:

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.  springapp  Build path JRE System Library Problem

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Resource leak: 'mongo' is never closed MongoSensorDao.java /springapp/src/main/java/com/conexiona/springapp/repository line 24 Java Problem

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The import java.net.UnknownHostException is never used MongoSensorDao.java /springapp/src/main/java/com/conexiona/springapp/repository line 3 Java Problem

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext is never used MongoSensorDao.java /springapp/src/main/java/com/conexiona/springapp/repository line 5 Java Problem

Comment: And finally. Description Resource Path Location Type
The method getDB(String) from the type Mongo is deprecated MongoSensorDao.java /springapp/src/main/java/com/conexiona/springapp/repository line 26 Java Problem

Comment: Thanks in advance